# 500 Internal Server Error - Due to timing out?

Tags: php

I have a php page that runs a series of queries and loops as shown below, but I am getting a `500 Internal Server Error` which I can only assume is down to a timing out.

The main loop should loop through about 3000 records but I have added the **if** statement to check if it works with a lower number which it does (the userIDs are 1, 2, 3, 4 etc and therefore indicate the number of records being looped through). Up this number to 2000 and I get the error after about 1 minute.

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 9000); 
...
$sqlSelect = "SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM tblResults;";
$selectedIDs = mysql_query($sqlSelect);

while($resultRow = mysql_fetch_array($selectedIDs)) {
    $userID = $resultRow['userID'];
    set_time_limit(0);

    if ($userID < 500) {
        ....
        series of queries and loops
        ....
    }
}
```

I have tried setting the **max_execution_time** and have put **set_time_limit(0);** at the beginning of any loop but this does not seem to help. I can't find any errors in any of logs relating to the error.

Also, it is not an issue with the data as if I try:

```
    if ($userID >= 500 && $userID < 1000) 
    if ($userID >= 1000 && $userID < 1500) 
    if ($userID >= 1500 && $userID < 2000)   etc
```

it all works. But try:

```
    if ($userID < 2000) [ie the same data but all at once]
```

if fails.

Any thoughts?

Comment: 500 is an internal error, which is (or can be) something different than a timeout. In fact, any fatal error in the script will result in a 500, so it could be a syntax error or a fatal error due to calling of an undefined function or class. You should really enable error reporting or check the logs to see what is going on.

Comment: More likely to be another limit like memory.

Comment: @GolezTrol I don't change any of the script, just the number of times it loops. It works fine unless I change the number of loops to up to 2000 or more.

Comment: @arkascha I have increased the memory using ini_set('memory_limit','16M'); but I still get the error. How can I find out how much I might need?

Comment: If that really is the issue, then there is no sense it raising the limit more and more. There is a very good reason for the limits. Instead you should try to implement your stuff such that it scales better, that its memory consumption is constant, regardless of how many iterations you use.

Comment: How is this script executed?

Comment: If it is a memory error at all. Runtime errors can also occur due to invalid input somewhere, caused by specific data which is retrieved from the database in one of the later iterations. Before trying to increase the limits even more or optimize the code, I would first make sure that that is actually the error.

Comment: @arkascha a fair point. I didn't realise that what I was actually doing might be exceeding any memory limit.

Comment: As said: I do not know if that is the case. First thing you have to do is find out what the actual issue is. For that you have to take a look into your http servers error log file. There you can simply read what the issue is. Then you know what to do.

Comment: @RichardGriffiths Also are you looking at your error log to see the exact 500 error you're receiving so that you aren't guessing as to the cause??

Comment: The PHP logs should give you a more specific error message that will pinpoint the exact problem. If you look at the logs you will likely find the error in a matter of seconds.

Comment: If you have ssh access you could do: `df -h`, some time ago we had a trouble like this, the next was  a "table crashed"

Comment: @PanamaJack There is nothing in any error log that I can find.

Comment: I meant Check your **web server** error log. If you don't know where they are, look in the config file for the web server. What is your webserver? e.g. apache2.conf/httpd.conf or nginx.conf. That usually shows the where the log is setup.

Answer (score 0):

As a DBA I belive it to be wise to move some of the logic to the SQL instead. Since you don't specify the rest of the queries the best option could be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT userID FROM tblResults where userID < 500
```

Combine this with the rest of your queries I bet the execution time should decrease. Since > 1 minute execution for 2000 iterations seems a bit long, suggesting you have some nasty stuff going on in that loop :)

Comment: This kind of defeats the object as the procedure needs to loop through the full data set of over 2000 users. It is not so much nasty stuff inside as quite a lot of it.

Answer (score 0):

Would you try to run this code ?

```
while($resultRow = mysql_fetch_object($selectedIDs)) {
        $userID = $resultRow->UserID;

        if ($userID < 500) {
            ....
            series of queries and loops
            ....
        }
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure I made one point clear. The userIDs a 1, 2, 3, 4 etc. Therefore from 1 to 500 is all < 500. It is not the getting of the userID - this is fine. It is the fact that if I loop through over a certain number (e.g. userID > 1000) I  get the error.